# Cesium flyto going crazy in 2d mode

Tags: 2d, cesiumjs

Everything works great in 3d mode, but i switch to 2d mode, globe keeps on transitioning. Am i suppose to use fly to in the instance or do i have to you use the Rectangle method. when I click 2d i want to stay in its current location. Any Ideas? Add more code so it can maybe you guys figure out what the issue is.

```js
private getCurrentCameraState(){
        if (this.map.scene.mode === 3) {
            return {
                x: this.map.camera.position.x,
                y: this.map.camera.position.y,
                z: this.map.camera.position.z,
                heading: this.map.camera.heading,
                pitch: this.map.camera.pitch,
                roll: this.map.camera.roll
            };
        } else {
            return {
                x: this.map.camera.position.x,
                y: this.map.camera.position.y,
                z: this.map.camera.position.z
            };
        }
    }
private applyCameraState(cameraState: ICameraState) {
        if (
            cameraState && this.map.scene.mode === 2) {
            console.log('2d');
            const destination = new Cesium.Cartesian3(
                cameraState.x,
                cameraState.y,
                cameraState.z
            );
            // this.globeDispatcher.setCameraTransition(true);
            this.map.camera.cancelFlight();
            this.map.camera.flyTo({
                destination: destination,
                complete: () => this.globeDispatcher.setCameraTransition(false)
            });
            
        } else if (cameraState &&
            !isEqual(cameraState, this.getCurrentCameraState()) && this.map.scene.mode === 3) {
                console.log('3d')
                const destination = new Cesium.Cartesian3(
                    cameraState.x,
                    cameraState.y,
                    cameraState.z
                );
                this.globeDispatcher.setCameraTransition(true);
                this.map.camera.cancelFlight();
                this.map.camera.flyTo({
                    destination: destination,
                    orientation: {
                        heading: cameraState.heading,
                        pitch: cameraState.pitch,
                        roll: cameraState.roll
                    },
                    pitchAdjustHeight: this.globeConfig.flyToPitchAdjustHeight, // Point Towards the Earth during flight
                    duration: this.globeConfig.flyToDuration,
                    complete: () => this.globeDispatcher.setCameraTransition(false)
                })
        } else if (cameraState === undefined) {
            console.log('undefined')
            // Initialize camera state if undefined
            this.globeDispatcher.setCesiumCameraState(
                this.getCurrentCameraState()
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to add a to add a small timeout:

```js
scene.morphComplete.addEventListener(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    camera.flyTo({
      destination: Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(-74.0, 41.0, 15000.0)
    });
  }, 300);
});
```

Comment: still getting the same results

Comment: Added the code i have right now to your comment @alex monti

Comment: can you provide more info about the code? i thougth was referred in a known ban.

Comment: just added more code, hoping that helps @alex monti

Comment: Or maybe how do i create a rectangle using x y z